# Logout and clear cookies programatically from controller in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security

I would like to logout programatically using spring boot security in the line that I indicated with the arrow below in my home controller.

****The things I tried:****
I was looking at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-logout-handler) article and it is not clear to me how and when is /logout called? I do not want the user to logout with a button or going to a logout endpoint.

I also watched the YT video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CqWDqWaNk) but it again uses a form action for /logout. It uses the Logout URL and the Logout Success URL.

I could use the logoutSuccessHandler to clear the cookies but again I do not know how to call the logout programatically that would then invoke the logoutSuccesHandler.

```
   @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index(Principal principal) throws IsimConnectionException {
            Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;
    
    
            if ((authentication.getPrincipal() != null) && (authentication.isAuthenticated())) {
                
                String shortname = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
    
                sessionScopedLdapUser.shortname(shortname);
    
                
                if (isimConn.hasid()) {
                    **** ---> here I would like to logout and clear cookies
                    return "hasid";
                } else {
                    return "needsLinking";
                }
    
            }
            return "index";
        }
```

Here is my websecurity config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private LdapAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    /**
     * Defines the web based security configuration.
     *
     * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/sw.js").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login") //custom login page
                    .permitAll() // permit everyone the /login page
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));

    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom authentication provider.
     *
     * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }



}
```

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare as I described in my code above in my question, based on the business logic in my home controller I decide when to logout the user and invalidate all the cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    boolean isSecure = false;
    String contextPath = null;
    if (request != null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        isSecure = request.isSecure();
        contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    }
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    context.setAuthentication(null);
    if (response != null) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", null);
        String cookiePath = StringUtils.hasText(contextPath) ? contextPath : "/";
        cookie.setPath(cookiePath);
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        cookie.setSecure(isSecure);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

You can call the above method from anywhere to logout from Spring Security. You can pass null for request and response but then it will not invalidate http session and clear cookies in that case.

Comment: Thanks so much @shazin. Will the logout method you wrote in the answer also invalidate a sessionscoped bean?

Comment: Also if I understand it correctly I do not need the following configuration in my webconfig class if use your logout method. Is that correct @shazin?
`.and().logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))`

Comment: @Anuska Answer for 1st question Yes if you pass request then it will invalid session invalidating all session scoped beans theoretically. 2nd question, Yes you don't need that part as you are not calling the `/logout` url to logout

Comment: Great. Many thanks @shazin.